How to remove the active state on a button when clicking on an input
I am building a component with 4 preset buttons and a custom range input. I am able to toggle the active state on the buttons when clicking them but I want to remove the active state from all the buttons when I click into the input. I also want to clear the input field when I click out of the input.
code:


let btnContainer = document.getElementById("rc-button-bar");
let btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("ce-button");
let input = document.getElementById("customPercent");

for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    (document.querySelector('.is-active')) ? document.querySelector('.is-active').classList.remove('is-active'): '';
    this.classList.add('is-active');
  });
}
.btn-primary.ce-button {
  width: 100%;
  height: 48px;
  padding: auto;
  border: 4px solid #0079c1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: transparent;
  color: #0079c1;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-primary.ce-button:hover,
.btn-primary.ce-button:active {
  background: #0079c1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer !important;
}

.is-active {
  background: #0079c1 !important;
  border-radius: 5px !important;
  color: #ffffff !important;
  font-weight: bold !important;
}
<div class="row selectors d-flex justify-content-center" id="rc-button-bar">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-2 mb-2">
    <button id="btn-25" class="btn-primary ce-button" data-value="25">25%</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-2 mb-2">
    <button id="btn-50" class="btn-primary ce-button" data-value="50">50%</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-2 mb-2">
    <button id="btn-85" class="btn-primary ce-button is-active" data-value="85">85%</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-2 mb-2">
    <button id="btn-100" class="btn-primary ce-button" data-value="100">100%</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-2 mb-2 d-flex align-items-center">
    <input id="customPercent" class="numbers" type="text" placeholder="ex: 80"></input>&nbsp;<span>%</span>
  </div>
</div>




What's stopping you from adding a click handler to the input that does what you want?

You're not actually changing the active state, you're just changing the is-active class. They're not the same thing.

You are not actually changing the active state of a button but just the appearance. But I will assume that was just a miscommunication error and that you only want to change the style it has after being clicked.
That is relatively simple. Just add a click event listener to the input and make it remove the 'is-active' class of the buttons (if they have it):
    input.addEventListener('click', function() { //add on click function
     for (let a = 0; a < btns.length; a++) { //loop through the buttons
       if (btns[a].classList.contains('is-active')) { //look for the class
         btns[a].classList.remove('is-active'); //remove the class
        }
      }
    })

To clear the input when you click out of it just add a blurr event listener that resets its value as an empty string:
    input.addEventListener('blur', function() {  //add function
       input.value = ''; //clear the input
    });

Run the whole code below to see that it works:


let btnContainer = document.getElementById("rc-button-bar");
let btns = btnContainer.querySelectorAll(".ce-button");
let input = document.getElementById("customPercent");

for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    (document.querySelector('.is-active')) ? document.querySelector('.is-active').classList.remove('is-active'): '';
    this.classList.add('is-active');
  });
}

input.addEventListener('click', function() {
  for (let a = 0; a < btns.length; a++) {
    if (btns[a].classList.contains('is-active')) {
      btns[a].classList.remove('is-active');
    }
  }
})

input.addEventListener('blur', function() {
  input.value = '';
});
.btn-primary.ce-button {
  width: 100%;
  height: 48px;
  padding: auto;
  border: 4px solid #0079c1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: transparent;
  color: #0079c1;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-primary.ce-button:hover,

.btn-primary.ce-button:active {
  background: #0079c1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer !important;
}

.is-active {
  background: #0079c1 !important;
  border-radius: 5px !important;
  color: #ffffff !important;
  font-weight: bold !important;
}
<div class="row selectors d-flex justify-content-center" id="rc-button-bar">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-2 mb-2">
    <button id="btn-25" class="btn-primary ce-button" data-value="25">25%</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-2 mb-2">
    <button id="btn-50" class="btn-primary ce-button" data-value="50">50%</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-2 mb-2">
    <button id="btn-85" class="btn-primary ce-button is-active" data-value="85">85%</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-2 mb-2">
    <button id="btn-100" class="btn-primary ce-button" data-value="100">100%</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-2 mb-2 d-flex align-items-center">
    <input id="customPercent" class="numbers" type="text" placeholder="ex: 80"></input>&nbsp;<span>%</span>
  </div>
</div>



